# Return provider count as zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I return both PROV_ID's from a query below. 454 returns 8 but 323 doesn't return any value since it is not in table. I'd like it to show 0. Using SQL Server.

```
SELECT PROV_ID
    , COUNT(PROV_ID) AS PROVS
FROM CLAIMS
WHERE PROV_ID IN (323,454)
GROUP BY PROV_ID
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `VALUES` virtual table, and left join the main table

```sql
SELECT
  v.PROV_ID,
  COUNT(c.PROV_ID) AS PROVS
FROM (VALUES
  (323),
  (454)
) AS v(PROV_ID)
LEFT JOIN CLAIMS c ON c.PROV_ID = v.PROV_ID
GROUP BY
  v.PROV_ID;
```

Note that `COUNT(*)` returns the total number of rows, and `COUNT(c.PROV_ID)` returns the number of non-nulls, and left-join will return null for no match.